# Will it save a lot of memory by using 9-patch images?

Tags: android

I am fighting against OutOfMemoryError in my app.

I created a background image, which is 800 pixel x 480 pixel. When this image is loaded into the view that uses it as background, I think the OS will use 800*480*4 bytes for it. It is a lot of memory.

If I create a 10 pixel x 10 pixel 9-patch image to replace the whole screen image. The OS will auto-scale the 9-patch image to 800x480 when it renders the view that uses the 9-patch. My question is that, in the 9-patch case, how much memory will OS use to draw the scaled 9-patch image? will it be 10*10*4 bytes or 800*480*4 bytes?

Thanks.

Comment: have you figured this out yet, im wondering the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if it is a background image, and could be scaled, please do so, as it is known to be the best practice (especially for backgrounds) and the slight loss of image clarity could be compensated by choosing the correct colours and/or background pattern.

Regarding memory, if you are using Drawable you are on the safe side. But the Bitmaps are apparently not allocated in a standard Java way but via native calls; the allocations are done outside of the virtual heap, but are counted against it. [More on this problem here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/6659aaf069e462d2/e0ceb02a91a487ce?#e0ceb02a91a487ce)

Comment: I know the image data is in native heap. My question how much native heap will the 9-patch image use, 10*10*4 bytes or 800*480*4 bytes?