# does 9 patch take more memory when stretched?

Tags: android, memory, heap-memory, nine-patch

ive looked around for days and i cannot find the answer i have about 70 images that i am trying to do frame animation with. right now i have them at a lower resolution so i can avoid outofmemory exception. but they show a bit blurred. im thinking about converting to 9 patch and i have a couple questions about it.

1. if i use the same lower resolution images will they scale up and not be blurry.
2. does 9 patch images take more heap memory when they are scaled up?
3. does a 9 patch image take less memory than a png?

note: these images are a full screen image on one imageview taking up the whole screen

edit: also this is for an app that is already published and i made it with eclipse about 4-5 years ago, im asking all of this mainly because if i do an update i dont want to get any outofmemoryexceptions so i am doing as much research as i can before i do an update

thank you for your time

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394426/will-it-save-a-lot-of-memory-by-using-9-patch-images